# XPath not working for one of the selenium scenario

Tags: selenium, xpath, cucumber

**HTML**

```
<div data-testid="signin-back-button" class="white-arrow">
     <a href="/" class="back-text" onclick="backBtnClick()">
         <img class="back-arrow-white" src="/images/arrow-left-white.svg" aria-hidden="true">
              Back
      </a>
</div>
```

I have written **xpath** as

```
//a[@onclick='backBtnClick()']/img[contains(text(),'Back')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not need to rely on **text**, please use below **xpath**

```
//a[@onclick='backBtnClick()']//child::img[contains(@src,'images/arrow-left-white.svg')]
```

Answer (score 0):

use **double slash** in your **xpath**

```
//a[@onclick='backBtnClick()']//img[contains(text(),'Back')]
```